# C++ Is it legal to use .. (dot dot) in #include directive?

Tags: c++, include, include-path

there. As title saying.
Use `#include"test.h"` is legal.
Use `#include"test/test.h"` is also legal.
But is it legal to use `#include"../test.h"`?

For example, `#pragma once` is legal in almost every compilers.
But this is not standard in C++.

I cannot find any documents which saying .. "guarantee" to be meaning of parent directory.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: yes its legal, but make sure that whenever you making binary then parent directory of your binary directory consist that test.h file.

Comment: Relative paths like "../test.h" are perfectly legal. The path will be applied relative to your "Include Path". So, Your include path includes the folder of the current source file being compiled, as well as other folders that you configure with your project settings. So it will look for a test.h in the parent folder of each of those.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say clearly.
Is C++ standard guarantee .. means parent directory?

Comment: @MrLister concern of my comment was, parent directory of binary file should consist test.h file..

Comment: @EdHeal: Why would "trying" it tell the OP if it was legal C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard says in §2.8/1:

> Header name preprocessing tokens shall only appear within a `#include`
>   preprocessing directive (16.2). The sequences in both forms of
>   header-names are mapped in an **implementation-defined manner to headers
>   or to external source file names** as specified in 16.2.

So here you have it: It's all implementation-defined. §16.2 then says, among some other things not directly related to your question:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `#include` `"`*q-char-sequence*`"` *new-line*
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the
>   source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"`
>   delimiters. **The named source file is searched for in an
>   implementation-defined manner.**

And this makes a lot of sense. Why shouldn't you be able to create a C++ compiler for file systems that do not use the ".." convention?

In summary, to answer your question: Yes, it is legal according to the C++ standard, but that's not surprising because almost everything is technically legal for an `#include` directive.

The more interesting question is what the documentation of your C++ implementation has to say about this. But even then you may be left with a rather generic explanation on the topic. For example, the [MSVC 2015 documentation for `#include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) says:

> The *path-spec* is a file name that may optionally be preceded by a
>   directory specification. The file name must name an existing file. The
>   syntax of the *path-spec* **depends on the operating system** on which the
>   program is compiled.

Comment: Given that it's legal to do so, what I'm curious about is if it's good practice to do so. I have no objections against other than it looks "ugly", but a more experienced C++ programmer may have better insight.